# R Wrong encoding in console captured object (Cyrillic encoding)

Tags: r

I have a problem with console output encoding. When I just check my locale, it says I have the right one:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"
```

All the objects appear to have the right one too, but when I try to save the console output like this:

```
dataStr <- data.frame(capture.output(str(data)))
```

The dataframe `dataStr` somehow has UTF-8 encoding:

```
> Encoding("���") #This string is an example what I receive
[1] "UTF-8"
```

I tried to set locale manually when I run script, but nothing happens:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia.1252")
Sys.setlocale(,"ru_RU")
```

When I run this script in RStudio or R colsole - the locale is right. But I need to pass this data.frame to the external application. By the way when I pass any object not from capture.output - the locale is fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, how to fix the encoding, but you might like the solution to use `summary.default` instead. It won't show you the data samples, but at least you'll get the data types and columns with the right encoding

Comment: Thank you! This is almost what I need. Would be better to see str() output, but I will use `summary.default`